# Django views updated several times

Tags: python, django, templates

When I am debugging my django project I see that my view  is updated several times in the console:

```
Hello
[05/Oct/2015 08:11:48]"GET /Appl/Products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10899
Hello
[05/Oct/2015 08:11:48]"GET /static/Start%20Application/jquery/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1753
[05/Oct/2015 08:11:48]"GET /Appl/Products/%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 200 10899
Hello
[05/Oct/2015 08:11:48]"GET /Appl/Products/js/queryLoader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10899
[05/Oct/2015 08:11:48]"GET /static/Start%20Application/jquery/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1753
```

This is my code:

```
def products(request):
    print "Hello"
    template = loader.get_template('Template.html')
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show your urls.py.

Comment: You might have forgot a `$` in the end of the URL configuration line that matches `^/Appl/Products/$`, so that it matches everything that starts with that path.

Comment: As well as the missing `$`, the `%7B%%20static` in the url suggests that you have used the `{% static %}` tag incorrectly in your template.